Orientation of a manifold given the definition provided in Milnor’s book
In Milnor’s book Topology from the differentiable viewpoint the definition of an orientation of a smooth manifold is introduced as follows :

Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^k$ be a m-dimensional smooth manifold. An orientation on $M$ is smooth choice of an orientation of each tangent space $TM_x$ for $x\in M$. That is, a choice of an orientation for all $TM_x$ such that for all $x\in M$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ and a local parametrization $h$ from $U$ to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $dh_x : TM_x\to \mathbb{R}^m$ preserves the orientation for all $x\in U$. The orientation considered on $\mathbb{R}^m$ is the one given by the canonical basis.

I am trying to prove that if a smooth manifold is orientable, there exists at least two orientations. In trying to prove this, I realized that something is really wrong in my attempt, so I would like to have your help on this please.
In order to be complete, here is my attempt :
Let $M$ be an orientable smooth manifold that is it has an orientation. We denote by $\pi_x$ the orientation chosen on $TM_x$ (that is a choice of an equivalence class) for all $x\in M$. Let $x\in M$ be fixed, there exists a neighborhood $U$ intersecting M such that for all $u\in U$, $dh_u$ preserves the orientation. That is, for a basis $(v_1,…,v_m)$ of $TM_u$ we have that $(dh_u(v_1),…,dh_u(v_m))\in [e_1,…,e_m]$ where $(e_1,…,e_m)$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$.
Now let $-\pi_x$ be the other equivalence class of $TM_x$. My idea was to introduce the map $g(x)=(x_2,x_1,…,x_m)$ with $dg=g$ in order to take a basis $\alpha$ in $-\pi_x$ and and get that $d(g\circ h)(\alpha)\in [e_1,…,e_m]$ by the fact that the determinant is alternating. However this does not work because the map is no more orientation preserving and even worse it is not well defined in general.
If you have some idea on what is my confusion on this do not hesitate to comment or answer please.
Thank you a lot

Try first to prove the result for $\mathbb{R}^n$

As a vector space ? It is clear from the fact that the determinant of the change of basis matrix is either positive or negative and thus only two orientations (equivalence classes) ?

Flip the orientation on each tangent space

@Mason Thank you for your comment ! If I do this without changing the map $h$, I have that $dh_u$ does not preserve the orientation with respect to the canonical basis since I am taking the « opposite equivalence class » for which it works ?
